# I get this error missing index.htm file when trying this codesandbox locally

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Just simple beginner question learning Reactjs and wanted to get this [Webpack Starter Kit working](https://codesandbox.io/s/webpack-4-forked-z9z4z?file=/webpack.config.js) since it's working at the Sandbox.

When using same code in Visual Studio Code I get this error and wanted help how to fix it

I have been trying lots of things for hours like:

I tried adding the `app` folder and template index.html
I tried to change devServer start path
I tried HtmlWebpackPlugin options
I tried modeling with the index.html
I tried setting `HtmlWebpackPlugin` template path "src/app/index.html"

```
    ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
      Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'L:\temp\webpack-4\app\index.html' in 'L:\temp\webpack-4':
      Error: Can't resolve 'L:\temp\webpack-4\app\index.html' in 'L:\temp\webpack-4'
    
      - compiler.js:79
        [webpack-4]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
    
      - Compiler.js:306
        [webpack-4]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:306:11
    
      - Compiler.js:630
        [webpack-4]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:630:14
    
    
      - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
        [webpack-4]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
    
      - Compiler.js:627
        [webpack-4]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:627:30
    
    
      - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
        [webpack-4]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
    
      - Compilation.js:1325
        [webpack-4]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1325:35

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":

    ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'L:\temp\webpack-4\app\index.html' in 'L:\temp\webpack-4'
```

Comment: You have the same error after adding `/app/index.html` file? You can try add path.resolve call to template line for html plugin, like so `template: path.resolve(__dirname, "/app/index.html"')`

Comment: I tried what you suggested now it looks like [this](https://snipboard.io/RoM5XH.jpg). . Same error but also this cant resolve css. And the src/app/index.html is there. I have not changed the code a bit only added app dir and your suggestion so it's strange it's working in the sandbox right

Comment: You have `index.html` and `app` folder inside `src` folder. But it should be top level folder, next to `src`. Or change path inside webpack.config to `/src/app/index.html`. Try both with path.resolve and without (old way like you had before)

Comment: [Like this??](https://snipboard.io/TzdZIN.jpg)

Comment: Nope, next to src. One more level up. Outside of src. Move it here or change path to `/src/app/index.html`. You can actually move it wherever you want just make sure path matches the actual file location. Right now webpack looking for `/app/index.html`, but you don't have it, you only have `/src/app/index.html`.

Comment: I tried `/src/app/index.html` what you say now it looks like [this](https://snipboard.io/w3jDR5.jpg). I think maybe that solved it and introduced a new error

Comment: wait forgot "/src" slash

Comment: Hmmm ..[Strange not working](https://snipboard.io/Z9AoHU.jpg)

Comment: That's just not good template, I think. It works in codesandbox because codesandbox actually uses Parcel for compilation, not webpack. If you want to learn React I would suggest to user Create React App https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: I made [this](http://greta.portplays.com/) site with Create-React-App and now I want to transit it to using webpack. I come from Android Java c++ and learning React Fast

Comment: You actually don't need forward slash in the beginning, it was typo from my side. `src/app/index.html` is the right path. CRA already uses webpack, you can try to `eject` if you want

Comment: I cant eject i'm not that skillful in build process and managing right now